# How to do calculations in a loop from list of data?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, infinite-loop, timing

I wrote the code below to do the calculation for each variables.  I would like to know how to do this in one loop and to print out timing  each time a cycle of calculations is completed.  Another question is how to do timing on ParallelTable?  If I use //Timing on Table the actual time duration is correct. However on ParallelTable the time duration is not accurate for actual time it took to calculate.(Should I multiply it by number of Kernels used?)

```
ClearAll;
f1[a_,b_,c_]:=a*x^2+b*x^3+c;
f2[a_,b_,c_]:=a*x+b*x^2+c*(2-x);
x=Range[0,10,0.1];
a1=1;b1=1;c1=1;
f3=f2[a1,b1,c1]+f1[a1,1,c1];
f4=f1[a1,b,c1]*f2[a1,b1,c1];
f5=f3+f4;
plot1=ListPlot[f5,PlotLabel->Style[  " a=" <>ToString[a1]<>" b="<>       ToString[b1]<>" c="<> ToString[c1]]]

a2=1;b2=0.2;c2=2;
f3=f2[a2,b2,c2]+f1[a2,b2,c2];
f4=f1[a2,b2,c2]*f2[a2,b2,c2];
f5=f3+f4;
plot2=ListPlot[f5,PlotLabel->Style[  " a=" <>ToString[a2]<>" b="<>   ToString[b2]<>" c="<> ToString[c2]]]

a3=1;b3=3;c3=0.1;
f3=f2[a3,b3,c3]+f1[a3,b3,c3];
f4=f1[a3,b3,c3]*f2[a3,b3,c3];
f5=f3+f4;
plot3=ListPlot[f5,PlotLabel->Style[  " a=" <>ToString[a3]<>" b="<>    ToString[b3]<>" c="<> ToString[c3]]]

a4=0.1;b4=0.1;c4=0.1;
f3=f2[a4,b4,c4]+f1[a4,b4,c4];
f4=f1[a4,b4,c4]*f2[a4,b4,c4];
f5=f3+f4;
plot4=ListPlot[f5,PlotLabel->Style[  " a=" <>ToString[a4]<>" b="<>     ToString[b4]<>" c="<> ToString[c4]]]

GraphicsGrid[{{plot1,plot2},{plot3,plot4}}]
```

for loop coding I assign a={1,1,1,0.1} etc.

[image]

Comment: Use `AbsoluteTiming` to time parallel operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done much more easily. Here is one way.

First we get rid of `f3` and `f4`.

```
f1[a_, b_, c_] := a*x^2 + b*x^3 + c
f2[a_, b_, c_] := a*x + b*x^2 + c*(2 - x)
f5[a_, b_, c_] := f1[a, b, c] + f2[a, b, c] + f1[a, b, c]*f2[a, b, c]
```

Second we define a function to take the parameters and plot `f5`. To do the plotting it is not necessary to make a table.

```
plotF[{a_, b_, c_}, max_: 10] :=
  Plot[f5[a, b, c], {x, 0, max}, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"a = ", a, "  b = ", b, "  c = ", c }]]
```

Now we can make the grid.

```
params = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, .2, 2}, {1, 3, .1}, {.1, .1, .1}};
GraphicsGrid[ArrayReshape[plotF /@ params, {2, 2}]]
```

[image: grid]

Note there is no looping. In Mathematica there is seldom any need to write loops.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer but you might get one if you would simplify your coding. For example

```
f1[{a_, b_, c_}] := a*x^2 + b*x^3 + c
f2[{a_, b_, c_}] := a*x + b*x^2 + c*(2 - x)
f3[a_] := f2[a] + f1[a] + f1[a]*f2[a]

Grid[{
  Table[ListPlot[f3[a], PlotLabel -> "a = " <> ToString[a]],
   {a, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0.2, 2}, {1, 3, 0.1}}}]}]
```

[image]